How to fully annotate cosine similarity calculations for matrices?
I have found online all around that for annotating cosine similarity for vectors it is the following
Similarity Score = $\frac{\vec a  \cdot \vec b}{||\vec a|| * ||\vec b||}$
where $\vec a = [x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{n}]$ and $\vec b = [x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{n}]$
x is the embedding value after performing a sentence transformation
But how does one present the similar annotation but for matrices? Coding wise I perform the dot product between matrix $M$ and $N.T$ and then calculate the magnitude matrix for all elements. This results in a final matrix with all the cosine similarity scores.
I thought that it would annotate like this
$S_{n, m}$ =  $\frac{N  \cdot M}{||N|| * ||M||}$
where N and M are the matrices, and $S_{n, m}$ is the output matrix with the dimensions of the two that I performed the calculation on.
Is this wrong?

Let $\lbrace e_k\rbrace$ denote the standard basis vectors for ${\mathbb R}^n.\,$ Use them to extract the columns of $N$ and $M$
$$\eqalign{
\def\q{\quad}
n_j&=Ne_j,\q &A={\rm Diag}\!\left(\,\frac{\tt1}{\|n_j\|}\right) &= A^T \\
m_k&=Me_k,\q &B={\rm Diag}\!\left(\frac{\tt1}{\|m_k\|}\right) &= B^T \\
}$$
The matrices $\lbrace A,B\rbrace$ contain scale factors such that the columns of $NA$ and $MB$ are unit vectors that have the same direction as the respective columns of $N$ and $M$.
This admits a straightforward calculation of the $S$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
S_{jk} &= \big(NAe_j\big)^T\big(MBe_k\big) = e_j^T\big(AN^TMB\big)e_k
\q\implies\q
S &= A\,N^TM\,B \\
}$$
